# How to implement back to app functioning button in auth0?

Tags: auth0

I want to implement routing back to login page after resetting password from password change ticket in auth0. I tried changing the reset password success in advanced option but still not working. The back to login button is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to add the login URL to the Tenet login URL. you can find it Go to settings > advanced > Tenant login URL. Then add a redirect URL to the change password email template. If you want to customize the password reset success page you can go to branding > universal login > advanced options > custom text. you can choose the password change success window from that dropdown.